# QGIS apply full color ramp to values from Min to Max

Tags: qgis

When rendering data in QGIS using catergorized symbology the highest (lowest) value is automatically applied to "all other values".
Is there an option to ignore "all other values" or to somehow apply the entire color ramp to the data from min to max values?

In the screenshot below the data has values from 2018 to 2022. How would I apply the color scale so that 2022 has the highest value (yellow) instead of "all other values" (which do not exist) ?

[image: categorized color scale symbology]

Comment: Have you tried using graduated symbology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. 1.  Highlight the values you want to remove.  For example, highlight *all other values*  2. Use the negative symbol at bottom of the dialog box to remove the highlighted values. 3.  From the drop down Color ramp choose your desired color ramp again.  This will apply whiteish yellow to 2022 and 2018 will remain black.

Comment: this works and was simpler than expected :)